# InvalidOperationException Was unhandled - Explanation needed please

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am creating a user login for my software which is connected to Access, I keep on getting the same error which highlights the line '                    i = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();' saying...

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional information: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Username= 'MGRjs' AND Password 'Candy''.

```
    private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = F:\Loughborough\3rd Year\Individual Project\StockManagement system\Database.accdb");
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();

        int i = 0;
            if (IDtbx.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please log in");
            }
            command = new OleDbCommand("select count(*)from NewUser where Username= '" + IDtbx.Text + "' AND Password '" + PSWtbx.Text + "'", connection);

            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                connection.Open();
                i = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
            }

            connection.Close();
            if (i > 0) 
            {
                MainSystem mainForm = new MainSystem();
                mainForm.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(Login_FormClosed);
                mainForm.Show();
                this.Hide();
                LoginError.Visible = false;
            }

            else
            {
                LoginError.Visible = true;
            }

    }
```

Comment: `"Syntax error (missing operator)"` - Because you're missing the `=` operator in your `Password` comparison.  Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: It is obvious that you are missing `=` after password in the query. It should be `Password = '" + PSWtbx.Text + "'"`

Comment: Also, there's the obvious problems... Your code is wide open to SQL injection (you should be using query parameters instead of executing user input as code).  And you should ***never*** store user passwords in plain text.  User passwords should be *hashed* and should *not be recoverable* in their original form.

Comment: @David is not a typo but most likely duplicated

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is wrong so your database is raising and error.

```
select count(*)from NewUser where Username= 'blablalbla' AND Password 'whatever'
```

You are missing the `=` between the password and the value.

BTW, your code is prone to SQL Injection, please consider using parametrized queries yo avoid security flaws,